# How to add iterations on this liquid for loop

Tags: php, html, shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

How i add a numbers iterating on this for loop in place of {{i}}
Please note that this loop dont have a specific limit since it will get all ordered items no matter how many are them.

```
<img src="https://billiger.de/sale?shop_id=Acaraa&oid={{ order.order_number }}

{% for line_item in order.line_items %}
&aid_{{i}}={{ line_item.product_id }}&name_{{i}}={{ line_item.product.title }}&cnt_{{i}}={{ line_item.quantity }}&val_{{i}}={{ line_item.product.price | divided_by: 1.19  | times: line_item.quantity | money_without_currency}}
{% endfor %}

" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" />
```

So the loop should look like this

```
&aid_1=ARTICLE-ID-1&name_1=ARTICLE-NAME-1&cnt_1=ARTICLE-COUNT-1&val_1=ARTICLE-VALUE-1
&aid_2=ARTICLE-ID-2&name_2=ARTICLE-NAME-2&cnt_2=ARTICLE-COUNT-2&val_2=ARTICLE-VALUE-2
&aid_3=ARTICLE-ID-3&name_3=ARTICLE-NAME-3&cnt_3=ARTICLE-COUNT-3&val_3=ARTICLE-VALUE-3
```

PS: The above code will be used in shopify template file

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is a PHP port of Shopify's Liquid templating library for Ruby? If so, if the port is complete I assume it should have [`forloop.index`](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops#forloop-index) (or its zero-indexed conterpart `index0`).

Comment: I won't post an answer though because I am making an assumption that you are using a ported library - but I don't know which one as a couple have come up for me on Google. Can you provide a link to the library?

Comment: @DarraghEnright Im so sorry that i didnt mention on my question is that my question is related to a Shopify template liquid file

Comment: No problem, but you are using a PHP port right? [Is this it](https://github.com/harrydeluxe/php-liquid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forloop` object has a number of helper methods, including ones to count the current iteration of a loop:

- `forloop.index` which counts the loop iteration starting from 1
- `forloop.index0` which counts the loop iteration starting from 0

In your example you would modify your code to use the appropriate method instead of `{{i}}`; i.e:

```
<img src="https://billiger.de/sale?shop_id=Acaraa&oid={{ order.order_number }}

{% for line_item in order.line_items %}
&aid_{{forloop.index}}={{ line_item.product_id }}&name_{{forloop.index}}={{ line_item.product.title }}&cnt_{{forloop.index}}={{ line_item.quantity }}&val_{{forloop.index}}={{ line_item.product.price | divided_by: 1.19  | times: line_item.quantity | money_without_currency}}
{% endfor %}

" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" />
```

I am assuming you want to start counting the iterations from `1` here, but just use `forloop.index0` if you want to start from `0`.

[Here is the documentation for `forloop.index`](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops#forloop-index) for Shopify's official Liquid library (in Ruby).

Since you have tagged your question as PHP, it would appear that you are using the [php-liquid](https://github.com/harrydeluxe/php-liquid/) port of the library - it appears in Shopify's list of [Liquid ports](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Ports-of-Liquid-to-other-environments).

This port does not seem to have any detailed documentation but if you look at the [unit tests](https://github.com/harrydeluxe/php-liquid/blob/master/tests/Liquid/Tag/TagForTest.php#L63-L73) you'll see that these forloop helpers have been implemented.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oops! Fixed a typo in the code - I wrote `foreach.index` when I meant to write `forloop.index`. Fixed now :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, it worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped :)